# angular airbnb-like calendar functionality

Tags: angular, date, calendar

I would like to implement the AirBnb-like calendar functionality ([check it out!](https://www.airbnb.com/) - tap on when) on my (angular2) application because it's super cool and user-friendly but at this point I couldn't find any module or solution that would fit. Besides that, I couldn't find any module that I could tweak.

I am currently using primeng calendar but I see no support for such thing.

I am looking forward to seeing your suggestions on how could I get to the solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following npm-package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-daterangepicker? 
Seems to do that you are asking for.